# Why use Javascript to trigger css transition only work for removing a class?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I pasted my code on JS Bin here: https://jsbin.com/yamisuvute/edit?html,output

If you click the green triangle, the transition is not trigged. But, if you click it again, you will see the transition works correctly.

I can not figure out why this happened. Please someone help me.

Comment: The opacity transition seems to be working fine. What is not transitioning is the left property, so when you hide it, it immediately moves to the left, and the opacity transition is no longer in the view.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this helps

try with following code ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Intro</title>
  <style>
    *{padding:0;margin:0;box-sizing: border-box;}
    html,body{width:100%;height:100%;}
    .container{margin:auto;width:100%;height:100%;}
    .nav{
      position:fixed;
      left:0;
      top:0;
      display: block;
      background: skyblue;
      width: 40%;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .nav-active{
        opacity: 1;
      transition: opacity 2s;
     -webkit-transition: opacity 2s;

    }
    .nav > ul{
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    } 
    .nav > ul > li {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto; 
      list-style: none;
    }  
    .nav > ul > li > a{
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 5px 5px;
      color: white;
      font-size: 25px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .nav > ul > li > a:hover{
      background: gray;
      color: white;
    }
    .menu-btn{
      display:block;
      position:fixed;
      top:0; left: 40%;
      width:0;height:0;
      border-top: 20px solid transparent;
      border-right: 20px solid transparent;
      border-left: 20px solid green;
      border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    }
    .menu-btn-left{left:0;}
    .nav-hidden{left:-100000px;opacity:0;} 
  </style>
  <script>
    var notClicked = true;
    function popMenu(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var nav = document.getElementsByClassName('nav')[0];
      var navHidden = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-hidden')[0];  
      var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-btn')[0]; 
      if(notClicked){
        nav.classList.remove('nav-active');
        nav.classList.add('nav-hidden');
        btn.classList.add('menu-btn-left');
      }else{

        nav.classList.remove('nav-hidden');
        nav.classList.add('nav-active');
        btn.classList.remove('menu-btn-left');
      }
      notClicked = !notClicked;
    } 
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="" class="menu-btn" onclick="popMenu(event);"></a>
    <nav class="nav nav-active">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
  <script>

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```